# ¿como agrego una variable dentro de system();?

Tags: c++

hola quisiera saber como puedo poner la variable dentro de system();}
quisiera saber la respuesta lo mas pronto posible ,gracias ;) lo he tratado de conseguir pero es
bastante difícil

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){
   
 int d;
 char x;
 cout<<"ingrese datos:";
 cin>>d;
 cout<<"ingrese url:";
 cin>>x;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
 {
    system("ping "x);//poner aca la variable x
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: La url no tiene que ser un `char`, tiene que ser un `std::string`. Ya usando `std::string`, puedes sumarlas (`std::string cmd("ping "); std::cin >> url; cmd += url`). PD: Usa `<cstdlib>` en lugar de `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: Los que aquí respondemos no cobramos por el tiempo que le dedicamos a las respuestas. Tenlo en cuenta la próxima vez que te urja una respuesta. No es nuestra obligación ayudarte, lo hacemos porque nos apetece. Dicho de otra forma, si vienes exigiendo o no recibirás respuestas o estas no serán todo lo completas que te gustaría (como es el caso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) recibe como parámetro un puntero a cadena de caracteres; lo que se conoce como *cadena de tipo C*. Al objeto `std::string` puedes pedirle ese tipo de datos con la función `std::string::c_str`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // Incluye esto, no incluyas <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; // usa nombres autoexplicativos
    cout << "ingrese datos:";
    cin >> dato;

    char url; // usa nombres autoexplicativos
    cout << "ingrese url:";
    cin >> url;
 
    stringstream comando;
    comando << "ping " << url;

    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    {
        system(comando.str().c_str());
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gacias por tu ayuda